# Insert Count Value in Correct Row

Tags: sql, select, count, where-clause, insert-into

I am trying to find all unique values and insert them into a new table,  line_list_progress. But I also want the unique value count to go in the correct row, called Completeness. When I run this query it throws a syntax error that the

> column name, data, is invalid.

The `data` column is part of the new table, `line_list_progress`.

How can I solve this?

Code:

```
Insert into line_list_progress (done)  
select count(distinct [Node Name3]) 
from A1 
where Data='Completeness';
```

Comment: does table `A1` have the `Data` column?

Comment: No, table A1 doesn't. Which is probably why this isn't working. But I guess my question is how do  you get it so that the data appears in the data column which is part of the new table, line_list_progress?

Comment: Please append the structure of your table `line_list_progress`and `A1`, or at least sample data with expected output to your query.

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: sqlserver @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: can you post some data sample and desire output?  please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the following data:  Table called XX_CAR -- it has multiple records per owner_id  -- fulfilling your requirement to have a count.  So what we want is to create a new table with the owner_id and count.  (your Data and Completeness)

```
    OWNER_ID    MAKE      HP
         111    BMW       180
         122    MASERATI  458
         133    LOTUS     635
         111    VOLVO     105
         111    SAAB      98
         122    FERRARI   735

    Insert into Line_List_Progress (Data, Completeness)
     SELECT OWNER_ID, COUNT(*)
     FROM XX_CAR
     GROUP BY OWNER_ID
```